# String explode then sort multiple single arrays defined by a index key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, explode, php-5.3

Using php 5.3, I am trying to sort the arrays descending.
I have the following multiple single arrays after a string explode:

```
Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 115
[2] => 20
)
Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 140
[2] => 50
)
Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 120
[2] => 40
)
```

The output I am looking for would be to sort ascending by `key[1]` so it will look like this:

```
 Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 115
[2] => 20
)
Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 120
[2] => 40
)
Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 140
[2] => 50
)
```

The code I have so far is :

```
$data = string_content_to_explode

foreach($data as $line) {

    if(substr($line,0,1)=="A") {

    $parts = explode(chr(9), $line);

// sort awards DESC
array_multisort($parts[1]);
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($parts); echo "</pre>";
```

Unfortunately this has no effect whatsoever.
I can not find a function or example of a foreach which can sort multiple single arrays in this way. If someone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Did you see this http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php already?

Answer (score 0):

Sort it with [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
 usort($string_content_to_explode,function($a,$b){
     if ($a[1] == $b[1])
         return 0;
    return ($a[1] < $b[1])? -1: 1; 
 });


 var_dump($string_content_to_explode);
```